# mail command not setting sender address correctly

Tags: postfix

in my nagios, i have setup email to goto alerts@myd.com but when email is sent to this email id , it is sent to domain like $@mon.myd.com.

Why does email goes to $@mon.myd.com (mon.myd.com is the hostname of server)

Here is the log entry in the postfix when email is sent.

```
Oct  1 08:24:05 mon postfix/pickup[11811]: 73262140BA8: uid=1001 from=<support@branchost.com>
Oct  1 08:24:05 mon postfix/cleanup[10125]: 73262140BA8: message-id=<20171001082405.73262140BA8@mon.myd.com>
Oct  1 08:24:05 mon postfix/qmgr[10872]: 73262140BA8: from=<alerts@myd.com>, size=787, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct  1 08:24:05 mon postfix/smtp[10127]: 73262140BA8: to=<$@mon.myd.com>, relay=10.0.0.12[10.0.0.12]:25, delay=0.04, delays=0.02/0/0.01/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 78A99400E7)
Oct  1 08:24:05 mon postfix/qmgr[10872]: 73262140BA8: removed
```

output of grep email

```
root@mon:~# grep email /etc/nagiosql/contacts.cfg
        host_notification_commands      notify-host-by-email
        service_notification_commands   notify-service-by-email
        email                           alerts@myd.com
```

Output of mail commands:

grep mail /etc/nagiosql/commands.cfg

```
command_name                    notify-host-by-email
command_line                    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\nState: $HOSTSTATE$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nInfo:$HOSTOUTPUT$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n" | /usr/bin/mail -r support@branchost.com -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Host Alert: $HOSTNAME$ $HOSTSTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$

command_name                    notify-service-by-email
command_line                    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$\n" | /usr/bin/mail -r support@branchost.com -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Service Alert: $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
```

Comment: We'll need to see the NAGIOS config to comment.  Start with the output of `grep email /etc/nagios/config/contacts.cfg` (or whichever file is appropriate to your NAGIOS setup).

Comment: @MadHatter: added in the question

Comment: OK, thanks.  What's interesting, as I'm sure you've noticed, is that the email logged is *from* the destination address, *to* the weird confusing address.  It makes me wonder if this is a bounce email *from* the NAGIOS-declared recipient *to* the NAGIOS-declared sender.  Could we see your email-generating config entries, eg `command_name    notify-service-by-email ...` and `command_name    notify-host-by-email ...`

Comment: @MadHatter: updated the question

Comment: Fair enough, thanks.  I don't think the problem is configured into NAGIOS, whatever it is, and I'm afraid we just ran off the end of my postfix knowledge (I'm a sendmail man, myself).  Hopefully someone who knows more postfix than me can shed light on what it's doing, and maybe why.

Comment: Looks like a bounce back email to me, but not a lot of data, get your postfix config right. This is nothing on nagios.

Comment: perhaps you meant -f, not -r in your notification command?

Answer (score -1):

You have defined the email command as event_handler, but that is not the way that this command should be used. For event handlers, the $CONTACTEMAIL$ macro is not available.